# XML format for blogs and/or CMS

Tags: xml, content-management-system, blogs

I'm writing my own blog/CMS engine (using WebApp and Google App Engine), and I'm looking for a light-weight XML format to use for content storage.

Is there some already existing format that could be used for this purposes?
Maybe some subset of the DocBook or ePub format? 
I had a look at those and they seem to be a little of overkill for what I want to do.

Then again WXR (Wordpress eXtended RSS) or the one from Pluxml (pluxml.org) might be suited as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As far as formats for blog content go, it is hard to beat [Atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29).

That said, XML makes for a really good transport mechanism, but a fairly poor storage mechanism. A real database is usually a better bet.

Comment: Indeed, Atom seems like a sensible choice if you have to use a file for storing content. Quite a while back I rolled my own blog, and I used RSS for storage (though I'd use Atom now); it sounds a bit backwards at first, but it makes a lot of sense -- all the right elements are there.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for compatibility with a specific platform, following their defined schema would be a good idea. Otherwise, just structuring your own XML will work since XSLT gives you the ability to transform the data to other formats as needed.